# Xcode 5 code completion not working in .h file

Tags: xcode5, codesense

In my project the code completion is not working in the .h file. Any suggestions ?

**EDIT:**

It shows up for direct imports but not for nested imports. Even for normal imports it shows only a list of names without the symbol to the left.

[image: picture of autocomplete when ns is typed]

Comment: Can we see the .h file as it is? This can often happen when there is a small issue somewhere in the file confusing XCode so seeing the code would allow us SO-ers to give a better answer

Comment: Its applicable for all .h files. Unfortunately i cant share the source. I edited my question above since it happens only in that particular case.

Comment: If it's all your files any chance the prefix file is invalid?

Comment: The project builds fine. Is there anything specific i should look out for ?